# 3D rendering glitch on old game

Tags: graphics, 3d, compatibility, direct3d

I'm only vaguely familiar with 3D graphics so I will explain this to the best of my abilities. I got ToonCar, an old game I used to play, running on my Windows 8.1 PC. On both my integrated Intel graphics card, as well as my Nvidia 840M, the game performs and sounds fine, but the 3D textures glitch all over the screen (see link below). All of the glitching textures seem to be .r3d files.

Compatibility mode for an older Windows OS hasn't helped, although running the game in reduced color mode, 640x480 resolution, and disabled display scaling for high DPI have been helpful.

In the game's setup there is a drop-down for "Video System", with the options being RGB emulation, Direct3D HAL, Direct3D T&L HAL, and Intel(R) HD Graphics Family. The game runs very slow on some of these modes but runs fine on the Intel option.

Is there any way to run the game on an older version of DirectX (I'm on 11.0) or OpenGL (I'm on 4.2), or are there options within the Nvidia Control Panel that could help me out? Even identifying the problem itself would be very helpful.

Here is a link to the video of the problem. Couldn't get my screen recording software to grab it, sorry about that. https://i.imgur.com/iqaKHDN.gifv

Comment: You can't install an 'older version of DirectX'. You already have the latest built-in. See [Not So Direct Setup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup/)

Comment: I figured. Any thoughts on how to fix the glitch itself?

Comment: That is not really true for the programs pov. The game will get a Direct3D device for the API and feature level it asks for, it doesn't magically get a `ID3D11Device5` when it asked for say a `IDirect3DDevice9`, and a `IDirect3DDevice9` on a modern OS/driver should still follow the API's it did on older one (including things like fixed-function pipeline). There is a small chance there is a bug in the modern implementation, but more likely a game bug never followed the API rules. Assuming you don't have the source, it would be difficult. A wrapper might work if you identify what is wrong.

Comment: @FireLancer sadly in last 2-3 years modern OpenGL gfx drivers got buggy in the old APIs so I would not be surprised if that is also the case for DirectX too.

Comment: @ZachBrown try to install  gfx drivers from their real vendors. MS releases are useless. If that does not help you can still use virtual pc or something similar...